A weird B movie/TV-series about a girl and parallel Universes
I need your help to find a weird TV movies (B series, I think).
As far as I remember, The movie is from the 80s/90s, it was in color and the language was English (I saw it translated into Spanish).
Details:

Introduction: 2 people from a "shadow Universe" appear and search for a girl who escaped from that "shadow Universe".
Weird "army" and people traveling through "parallel universe(s)"
The girl joins a man (doctor or medical doctor?) for help, he joins her in her "transdimensional/transuniversal travel".
The end: she and her companion end up in another "parallel" Earth. 

No memory of the characters or actor. But the girl had exotic weapons from the other Universe and she was a fighter.
At the beginning of the movie, 2 mysterious characters mentioned Earth (Perhaps they think our world is some king of shadow of theirs).

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Hi, I did not know stack exchange had this...Well... As far as I remember, it is a movie in the final of the eighties beginning of the 90s (I was shocked by it as teenager). I don't have more than some bits of images...It was in color, ...Time period  80-90s, language English (but I saw it translate it into Spanish). I could not see the full movie due to interferences...NO memory of the characters or actor. But the girl had exotic weapons from other Universe and she was a fighter. At the end, she and the medical or doctor who joins her (I don't remember the details).

It ends into a scene of some kind of statue. The movie ends there...Puzzling me! I am not sure if the title had something to do with Riders or something similar...

At the beginning of the movie, 2 mysterious characters mentions about Earth "Perhaps, they think our world is some king of shadow of theirs"...

The Lexx? Though it is a series instead of a movie. This seems to be the last season where they go into the shadow universe (the original universe is the light universe).

NO, it is not The LeXX,...It is previous to it, I think...
